# Check if File exists in directory ignoring the extension

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, ajax, file-io

I am using .NET 2.0 and Linq is out of question. I would like to check if file exists inside a directory **without knowledge of the file extension**.

I just need this logic done.

1.Check File exists in Directory using String Filename provided using search pattern leaving out the extension of the File

2.Get the Files if they exists and Databind to provide `Download links`.If file does not exist then start uploading the File.

**Update:**
`Directory.GetFiles()` and `DirectoryInfo.GetFiles()` indeed solves the part where in i check for File existence. As for the performance regarding FileInfo objects, these were only solution to my requirements of databinding to provide download links

Comment: And what part of it is not obvious to you? You already provided the solution in your attempt to write a question.

Comment: Why do you need a FileInfo object?

Comment: you can create a FileInfo object for each string in the resulting array... what is your problem ?

Comment: @Claus How do you get the full path to the File from string of file names? Instantiating a  new FilInfo for just getting the file path is too costly in my situation

Comment: @Steve the operation is costly in my situation

Comment: @Deeptechtons `Path + "\\" + Filename` - you have the path and the filename, ...

Comment: Its not more costly than the answer you accepted, it still creates FileInfo object internally..

Comment: Directory.GetFiles already gives you the full name. Quote from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wz42302f.aspx): "Returns the names of files (*including their paths*) that match the specified search pattern in the specified directory" (emphasis mine). What is the problem with it?

Comment: @Richard @Martinho yeah i agree with you guys.  But when it comes to step number 1.1 Providing files as download links would be easy using the `fileInfo[]` as dataSource do you agree with that?

Comment: @Someone who downvoted the question could you please say why ?

Comment: I downvoted because 1) the question is unclear: I don't understand the problem that needs solving; and 2) I don't like the accepted answer.

Comment: @Martinho and thanks for explaining great comment. But certain things fit certain requirements. When i came to know that providing download links would we easy using FileInfo objects then i had to go the costlier way hence accepted that as answer. concerned to Richards answer it was my first instinct to mark it as answer but considering extensibility i did not but voted up as good solution. I will make it a point to explain clearer and in details next time thanks again :D

Comment: @Deeptechtons: if you edit the question and clear that up, I'll be glad to remove the downvote :)

Comment: @Martinho Updated if still doesn't sound clear i can edit to my hearts content

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
DirectoryInfo root = new DirectoryInfo("your_directory_path");
FileInfo[] listfiles = root.GetFiles("dummy.*");
if (listfiles.Length > 0)
{
  //File exists
  foreach (FileInfo file in listfiles)
        {
            //Get Filename and link download here
        }
}
else
{
  //File does not exist
  //Upload
}
```

Hope this works

Comment: And apparently instantiating FileInfos through GetFiles is not too costly.

Comment: @Martinho commented in regard to comment on question

Answer (score 5):

To see if a file exists with that name, can you not just use..

However, **[Directory.GetFiles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wz42302f.aspx) already includes the full path**

```
string [] files = Directory.GetFiles(Path,"name*");
bool exists =  files.Length > 0;

if ( exists)
{
   //Get file info - assuming only one file here..
    FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(files[0]);

    //Or loop through all files
    foreach (string s in files)
    {
         FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(s);
         //Do something with fileinfo
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for pointing me in right direction, Your's could be answer but when extensibility comes @Hatake Kakashi answers looks good to me

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`DirectoryInfo.GetFiles()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8he88b63.aspx) to have a `FileInfo[]` instead of a `String[]`.

Comment: thanks for pointing me to think simple. I was using overloaded version instead